# Calling Connection string from App setings app.config file to C# code

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I'm trying to call a connection string from the app.config file to C# code. This is the app.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
 <appSettings>

<add key="connectstring" value="Data Source=server111;Initial Catalog=database1;        Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False; User ID=username;Password=password;Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>

 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is the C# code:

```
  private SqlConnection connStudent;  
  connStudent = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectstring"].ToString());
  connStudent.Open();
```

The code should be right, but I'm getting a Null Reference Exception, and while debugging the program, connStudent is always null and does not get the connection string .
The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: I don't think this solves your issue, but I believe the 'value' from app.config is already being returned as a string so there is no need for ToString().

Comment: The C# code you show is not compilable or even valid, so at least provide the full stacktrace of the exception to better figure where it "might" have been raised at. As of now it is most likely that 'connectstring' is not found in your appSettings and thus `AppSettings["connectstring"]` returns `null`. So make sure that your `app.config` file is actually "build into" the output directory, next to your executable, bearing the same name (like "my.exe.config").

Answer (score 3):

if you are using .NET 2.0 or above Use following

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Why the limitation on .NET 3.5+? The `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` property was available since .NET 2.0.

Comment: Still null. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Have you added ref to System.Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine. check to make sure your `copy to output directory` property is set to `copy always` or `copy if newer`. if that still doesn't work, try to delete temp `obj` files.

the following test code works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connectstring" value="Data Source=server111;Initial Catalog=database1;        Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False; User ID=username;Password=password;Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection connStudent;
                connStudent = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectstring"].ToString());
                //connStudent.Open();
                //connStudent.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        }

    }
}
```